# Seeking Feedback and Advice for My YouTube Video

Tags: editing, youtube

Hello fellow creators and enthusiasts,

I recently created a music clip featuring "Be Our Guest" from Disney's Beauty and the Beast and uploaded it to YouTube. I'm reaching out to this community seeking constructive feedback and advice on various aspects of the footage, we are planning to record other footage of this kind in the future, but we are newbies at video shoot / mouting.

Here are some specific points I'd appreciate input on:

Editing and Visuals: I aimed for a visually captivating experience that complements the iconic song. Did the editing flow well with the music, and are there any specific visual elements that could be improved or enhanced?

Audio Quality: Ensuring clear and high-quality audio is crucial for a music clip. Did the audio come across crisply, and are there any adjustments needed in terms of volume or balance?

Engagement: Did the video capture your attention throughout, and were there any moments where you felt disengaged or distracted?

Overall Impact: What was your overall impression of the video? Did it effectively convey the essence of the song and the scene it represents from Beauty and the Beast?

Suggestions for Improvement: Any additional thoughts or suggestions you have for enhancing the video's impact and appeal would be greatly appreciated.

Feel free to provide as much detail as possible, including specific timestamps or examples if applicable. Your insights will be immensely valuable in refining and enhancing this project.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to watch and provide feedback. I'm eager to hear your thoughts!

Warm regards,